# How can I generate ASV file from nanopore sequencing data?

Tags: ngs, nanopore

I am converting the fast5 file to fastq by using guppy basecaller after that by using kraken2 classified the sequence.

Now I am trying to generate ASV file.

Is this possible to generate ASV file from kraken output?

Or is this any other way to generate ASV file from nanopore sequencing?

I am new to nanopore sequencing data. I need help or suggestions to generate ASV file.

Thank you

Comment: What is an ASV file? You should add information about that file format to your question. [The first information I get](https://fileinfo.com/extension/asv) talks about MATLAB, which doesn't seem correct.

Comment: ASV: amplicon sequence variant

Comment: Dear @twinkle please do check the answer below and do consider upvoting/accepting. Its a good answer and it does help with site stats.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that kraken/kraken2 does anything similar to this.

Usually to get OTUs/ESVs I think that you want to use a tool that clusters your sequences into groupings that represent the same sequence, allowing for technical error.

Examples might include [dada2](https://benjjneb.github.io/dada2/) or [dadasnake](https://academic.oup.com/gigascience/article/9/12/giaa135/6011256), or [qiime](https://forum.qiime2.org/t/can-we-process-nanopore-data-using-qiime2/16156/4). This is after the technical steps for adapter/trimming/denoising steps.

kraken2 is more for classifying into known taxonomic categories based on a reference sequence, which is a related but distinct task.

I don't think that I understand what the ESV file format is supposed to look like. [This resource](https://cmap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/catalog/datasets/ESV.html) seems to have some info on processing data into ESVs, but it is not for nanopore. Possibly it is still useful for the final step of creating that file format. A [linked repository](https://osf.io/g7xsj/) has a ton of one-off scripts that may be helpful but are not very well documented. For example, here is a script that they use to generate TSV files which *may* be the "ASV"/"ESV" format:

```
#!/bin/bash
source activate qiime2-2018.8

for item in `ls */*table.qza`
    do
    name=`echo $item | cut -d\/ -f1`
    qiime tools export --input-path $item --output-path EXPORTS-GTDB-tax/$name
    mv EXPORTS-GTDB-tax/$name/feature-table.biom EXPORTS-GTDB-tax/$name.biom
    rmdir EXPORTS-GTDB-tax/$name
done

qiime tools export --input-path 11_ANT-28-5-SPA_seqs_classified_against_GTDB_r86.1_807F-1050R_primer_sliced/classification.qza --output-path EXPORTS-GTDB-tax/

sed -i '1c#OTUID    taxonomy    confidence' EXPORTS-GTDB-tax/taxonomy.tsv

#Tutorial here: https://forum.qiime2.org/t/exporting-and-modifying-biom-tables-e-g-adding-taxonomy-annotations/3630
for item in `ls EXPORTS-GTDB-tax/*biom`
    do
    filestem=`basename $item .biom`
    biom add-metadata -i $item -o EXPORTS-GTDB-tax/$filestem.with-tax.biom --observation-metadata-fp EXPORTS-GTDB-tax/taxonomy.tsv --sc-separated taxonomy
done

for item in `ls EXPORTS-GTDB-tax/*.with-tax.biom`
    do
    filestem=`basename $item .biom`
    biom convert -i $item -o EXPORTS-GTDB-tax/$filestem.tsv --to-tsv --header-key taxonomy
done
```